# How to align Angular Material 5 Toolbar title center with Flex

Tags: angular, css, flexbox, angular-material2

I'm using Angular Material for my Angular 5 project. I'd like to align the toolbar title to center.

In [their docs](https://material.angular.io/components/toolbar/overview), they mention:

> The toolbar does not perform any positioning of its content. This gives the user full power to position the content as it suits their application.
>
> A common pattern is to position a title on the left with some actions on the right. This can be easily accomplished with display: flex:

This is what I tried:

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <span class="title-center">TITLE</span>
</mat-toolbar>

.title-center {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

...but the title is still in the left.

I tried reading [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp) about flex, but couldn't figure out what to do.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Assuming the `mat-toolbar` has `display: flex` and `row` direction (which is normally the default), set `justify-content: center` on its parent, the `mat-toolbar`, or use [auto margin*](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins) on the `span`, giving it `margin: 0 auto`.

*In both cases one also need to remove `flex: 1 1 auto`, as that will make the `span` fill its parent, since its `flex-grow` has `1` (the first value in the shorthand `flex`)*

```
.title-center {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

---

Or, if to keep the existing CSS, also add `text-align: center` to it, as one normally does when e.g. center an inline element like a `span` in a block element like a `div`

```
.title-center {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

---

** With Flexbox, auto margins got an update, [https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins_)*